# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in my C program?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a word count program in C. It simulates the wc command in Linux/Unix. It compiles fine, but when I try to run it, it gives me a segmentation fault message. The program is supposed to run like this:

```
./mywc -c test.txt
1 2 12 test.txt /* 1 is number of lines, 2 is number of words, 12 is number of chars */
```

My code looks like this:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Enumerators */
enum { FALSE, TRUE };
enum { STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR };

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096
#define NAME_SIZE 12
#define MAX_LINES 100000

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

/* Globals */
char *fileName = NULL; // File name
char tmpName [NAME_SIZE];
int option = FALSE; // Return true if option is provided in command line
int charOption = FALSE; // Return true if -c is provided in command line
int wordOption = FALSE; // Return true if -w is provided in command line
int lineOption = FALSE; // Return true if -l is provided in command line
int standardInput = FALSE;
int c = 0; // Character being scanned
int nl = 0; // Number of lines in file
int nw = 0; // Number of words in file
int nc = 0; // Number of chars in file
int lineStart[MAX_LINES];
int fileOffset = 0;
int fd;

parseCommandLine(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      if (argv[i][0] == '-')
        processOptions(argv[i]);
      else if (fileName == NULL)
        fileName = argv[i];
      else
        usageError();
    }
    standardInput = (fileName == NULL);
}

processOptions(char* str) {
    int j;

    for (j = 1; str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
      switch (str[j]) {
        case 'c':
          charOption = TRUE;
          while ( EOF != (str[j] = fgetc(fileName) ) )
            nc++;
          break;
        case 'l':
          charOption = TRUE;
          while (c == fgetc(fileName) != 'Z')
            if (c == '\n')
                nl++;
          break;
        case 'w':
          charOption = TRUE;
          int state = 0;
          while (c == fgetc(fileName) != 'Z') {
            ++nc;
            if (c == '\n')
                nl++;
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
                state = 0;
            else if (state == 0) {
                state = 1;
                ++nw;
            }
          }
          break;
        default:
          usageError();
          break;
        }
    }
}

usageError() {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mywc -lwc [argv[1]]\n");
    exit(1);
;}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    parseCommandLine(argc, argv);
    processOptions(argv[1]);
    fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY); /* Open file */

    int flag[3] = {lineOption,wordOption,charOption};
    int stats[3] = {nl,nw,nc};

    if (!option)
        printf("%d %d %d %s\n",nl,nw,nc,fileName);
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (flag[i])
                printf("%d ",stats[i]);
        }
        printf("%s\n",fileName);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I could get some help on what could possibly be causing this error so my program can run correctly, I would be grateful. Also, I need some hints on getting rid of a few warnings in my program:

```
mywc.c: In function ‘parseCommandLine’:
mywc.c:41:15: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
      fileName = argv[i];
               ^
mywc.c: In function ‘main’:
mywc.c:96:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘open’ from incompatible pointer type
     fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY); /* Open file */
               ^
In file included from mywc.c:3:0:
/usr/include/fcntl.h:146:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
 extern int open (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __nonnull ((1));
            ^
mywc.c:102:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 5 has type ‘struct FILE *’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%d %d %d %s\n",nl,nw,nc,fileName);
         ^
mywc.c:108:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct FILE *’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%s\n",fileName);
         ^
```

Comment: Try "fileName = &argv[i]"

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the shown code but it seems like the compiler thinks that `fileName` is of type `struct FILE *`, might want to check if you got multiple declarations or some macro magic in a header.

Comment: `while (c == fgetc(fileName) != 'Z')` What is this? Did you mean `while ((c = fgetc(fileName)) != 'Z')`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is likely a source of segmentation faults in your program is the fact that you improperly call `fgetc` with the file name as an argument. You need to open a file pointer first, and then pass *it* to `fgetc` to read a character:

```c
FILE *fp = fopen(fileName); // open the file

// ...

int ch  = fgetc(fp); // read a character, using fp instead of fileName
```

This is what causes most of your errors.

In addition, all functions must have a return type in C. If you don't want to return anything, you need to use the return type `void`:

```c
// |
// V
void parseCommandLine(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // ...
}

// |
// V
void processOptions(char* str) {
  // ...
}
```

And lastly, you need to declare or define a function before you can use it. So in your program, you call `processOptions` inside `parseCommandLine`, even though `parseCommandLine` occurs before `processOptions` in your program. In this case, you need to put a declaration of `processOptions` somewhere above the definition of `parseCommandLine` in your program:

```c
void processOptions(char* str); // declaration of processOptions()
                                // notice that there's no function body

void parseCommandLine(int argc, char* argv[]) {  // definition of
                                                 // parseCommandLine()
  // ...
}
```